# You could be antagonizing newcomers

Tags: discussion, support, users, moderators

I've seen answers antagonizing newcomers and people that got out of the mainstream questions that could potentially yield significant learning/lessons.

What's the point of using a FOSS system if you're not gonna slowly learn from it?

I define antagonizing as basically hijacking the OP's reasoning with "implied impossibilities" or "unpractical erratic deductions", stuff like that. Transmitting YES, NO or Don't know.

This happens when an user has no clue of what is wrong.

Implied impossibilities can be avoided with a "summary" of the question based on the title along with the objective.

An example would be when an answer doesn't respond to an OP and someone simply responds, "This doesn't answer to the OP"

In this case we should comment with a reminder to the OP's question.

Something like : "Your answer is about GRUB installation but the question is about formatting the disk. Please edit your answer with corresponding information"

Comment: If you have a specific complaint, please make it. Otherwise, this post just reads like "I don't like user X". We can't judge the behavior if you don't provide specific instances of it.

Comment: Could you provide an example of this? I get you don't want to name names but without that this is meaningless, also it would give the accused user chance to defend them selfs.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks makes more sense now :) I looked through the user in questions profile and I see no evidence of "antagonizing newcomers", in fact he has an high accept rate from newer users recently. I think this comes down to, "I don't like the way this user answers questions, he should do it like this."

Comment: Totally agree, I'll be the change I want. Simple. TY

Comment: Sure, I get that but I would recommend you edit this in to a more "Take you time and give useful detailed answers" style of post that suggests improvements to all users as advice, just saying this here to one user is unlikely to have an effect on others.

Comment: @MarkKirby Surely will do

Comment: New users find this site, irc, launchpad, and / or forums difficult sometimes, which is why Ubuntu offers so may options for support.

Answer (score 12):

If you think somebody is being rude, flag that post/comment.
We'll talk to them if we think it's becoming a problem.

"Be nice" is a rule around here and the mods do everything we can to make sure people at least attempt to get along with others. Even if we have to beat it into them.